# SECOND VALUE FROM COLUMN

Tags: mysql, sql

i have:

```
   id value
    1 a
    2 b
    3 c,d
```

How do i get d?
If i'm doing "having value = c" it works, if i try the same thing with d, it's not!

Comment: **why** do you need `d`? Many ways to do this. It sounds like you have a query - [edit] your question and add your attempt to supplement

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: You should strongly consider normalizing such a table to first normal form.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like : `...where value like '%,d'`